# Does going to bed with a weapon increase my chance of survival?

Tags: die2nite

Currently I'm at the point in Die2Nite where my town is basically about to be destroyed(170 defense vs. 255 zombies in the best case scenario). However, I'm determined to be the last man standing. While I already have my house filled with defensive items, I'm wondering if I should load up a battery launcher or some other weapon and take it with me to bed. Will it improve my chances for surviving through the evening?

Comment: I saw a post suggesting this kind of thing on the global forums.  It looks like weapons *may* eventually account for a defensive boost to the person holding them, but right now, they do not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.** However some items that can be used as weapons will add to your homes Defense if left in your chest overnight. This includes heavy objects, such as the Beer Fridge, and some animals, such as the Fat Cat.

Comment: The beer fridge is just a decorative item, not a defensive one. I have one in my home and it doesn't add any defense points. To add defense points the item must be specifically flagged as a defensive item.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the *Fat Cat* only adds decoratively to your home.  I'm sure the *Guard Dog* would add some defense, though.